# reemplazo parrafo con el DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo una duda, por que esta funcion  ( la que esta sin comentar), la primera me funciona bien. 
Me da el siguiente error : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.
    at remplazar_parraf

```js
function remplazar_parrafo(){
/*
        var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
        var reemplazo = parrafo.children[0];

        var nuevoparrafo = document.createElement('p');
        nuevoparrafo.textContent='Parrafo remplazado';

        parrafo.replaceChild(nuevoparrafo,reemplazo);
        */

        var text = document.createTextNode('Parrafo remplazado');

        var  item =document.getElementById('parrafo').childNodes[0];

        item.replaceChild(text,item.childNodes[0]);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parrafo">
    <p>Este es mi primer parrafo</p>
    </div>
   
    <input type="button" value="Añadir nuevo parrafo" onclick=anadir_parrafo()><br>
    <input type="button" value="Insertar nuevo parrafo" onclick=insertar_parrafo()><br>
    <input type="button" value="Remplazar parrafo " onclick=remplazar_parrafo()><br>
    <input type="button" value="Borrar parrafo" onclick=eliminar_parrafo()><br>
    <input type="button" value="Clonar div" onclick=clonar_div()><br>
    
    <script src="ejercicio1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estas usando mal el atributo `childNodes` en el elemento `parrafo`, y solo debería ser utilizado en el `replaceChild`. Así `var ítem = document.getElementById('párrafo'); ítem.replaceChild(text, ítem.childNodes[0]);`

Comment: O también podrías hacer esto `item.innerHTML = text`

Answer (score 0):

Para que sea más sencillo solo hazlo de esta forma:

```
function reemplazar_parrafo(val) {
  var ítem = document.getElementById('parrafo');
  ítem.innerText = val;
}
reemplazar_parrafo('Texto reemplazado');
```